# How do I exclude a directory when raising a review using rbtools?

Tags: glob, rbtools

I see this option in [rbtools documentation](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/3.x/rbt/commands/post/#cmdoption-rbt-post-X), I need an example for its usage when excluding a directory and its contents.

-X , --exclude 
Excludes all files that match the given pattern from the diff. This can be used multiple times to specify multiple patterns. UNIX glob syntax is used for pattern matching.
Supported by: Bazaar, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Perforce, SOS, and Subversion.
Patterns that begin with a path separator (/ on Mac OS and Linux, on Windows) will be treated as being relative to the root of the repository. All other patterns are treated as being relative to the current working directory.
For example, to exclude all ".txt" files from the resulting diff, you would use "-X /'*.txt'".

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with following command:

```
rbt post -X "<toExcludeDirectory>/*" --open master..head
```